# Invert mousewheel direction for a particular window with AutoIt?

Tags: windows, winapi, input, mouse, autoit

I am using a program that for some reason uses mousewheel+up to zoom out and mousewheel+down to zoom in, I'd like to revert that so it improves my workflow as all the other programs that I use do the inverse. So I need to do that in AutoIt.

What I need it to do is wait for a mousewheel event, then prevent the default and scroll the mousewheel in the opposite correct direction.

My script is as follows (updated), I used the MouseOnEvent.au3 ( https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/64738-mouseonevent-udf/ ) for the events, however it seems like it executes only once because I remove the event with _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN/UP_EVENT) and try to reattach it, but if I don't do that, then I get some weird huge lag on my machine,

```
#include <AutoItConstants.au3>
#include <Misc.au3>
#include <MouseOnEvent.au3>
#include <TrayConstants.au3>

_MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT, 'MouseWUp')
_MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT, 'MouseWDown')

Func MouseWUp($iEvent)

    If WinActive("SAI") Then

        Switch $iEvent
            Case $MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT
                ;TrayTip("", "Mousewheel Up", 2, $TIP_ICONHAND + $TIP_NOSOUND)
                _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT)
                MouseWheel($MOUSE_WHEEL_DOWN, 2)
                _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT, 'MouseWDown')
        EndSwitch

    EndIf

EndFunc

Func MouseWDown($iEvent)

    If WinActive("SAI") Then

        Switch $iEvent
            Case $MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLDOWN_EVENT
                ;TrayTip("", "Mousewheel Up", 2, $TIP_ICONHAND + $TIP_NOSOUND)
                _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT)
                MouseWheel($MOUSE_WHEEL_UP, 2)
                _MouseSetOnEvent($MOUSE_WHEELSCROLLUP_EVENT, 'MouseWUp')
        EndSwitch

    EndIf

EndFunc

Func Main()
    While 1
        Sleep(200)
    WEnd
    Exit
EndFunc

Call("Main")
```

Comment: I don't know AutoIt, but it sounds like your calls to `MouseWheel()` are triggering the mouse wheel motion, no? I imagine what you want to do would require a hook (if you can't use a SAI plugin directly)...

Comment: SAI doesn't support plugins sadly that's why I am trying to do it with the script. However I found an include so I can now have events for the mouse, however they don't seem to work right. The events fire, but either fire once and never again or fire too many times that make my machine lag terribly.